# Square cards larger than 70mm (2¾″)

Tags: game-design, components

Many board games use square cards that are [70mm × 70mm](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Card_Sleeve_Reference#toc8), about 2¾″.

Are there any that use larger square cards?  If so, what's the largest square card that is in use?

I'm mainly interested if there are *any* square cards larger than 70mm. I'm working on a game that needs square cards, and 70mm isn't big enough. The company I'm at wants to use sizes of cards that are already in use, where possible.

The reason the cards need to be large is because people are putting tokens on top of them when they're in play, not because they have to display much information.

Comment: This kind of question is very hard to answer for sure. There could always be some game with strange cards that the answerer isn't aware of. Can you try and clarify what exactly you want, and why you want to know this? For example, are you interested in the largest *common* size, for cost or compatibility reasons perhaps?

Comment: I'm mainly interested if there are *any* square cards larger than 70mm.  The reason I'm asking: I'm working on a game that needs square cards, and 70mm isn't big enough.  The company I'm at wants to use sizes of cards that are already in use, where possible.

Comment: Great. That helps enormously.

Comment: If you cannot fit all the information in space that others found sufficient, your game is probably too complicated, and the cards try to do too much for the players to really keep in their heads.

Comment: Ther reason these cards need to be large is because people are putting tokens on top of them when they're in play, not because they have too much information on them.

Comment: What about using tokens of different sizes? The small cube counts as one. You can swap out 5 small cubes for a medium sized cube. 5 mediums make a large one. Just like money: no need for a large purse if you exchange your quarters for a dollar bill...

Comment: Four quarters may equal a dollar bill, but an apple and two triremes can't be added together very well.

Comment: Is it possible for you to consider cardboard tiles instead of cards? I've surely seen tiles bigger than 70mmx70mm. The Game Crafter prints [decks of square 3.5"x3.5" cards](https://www.thegamecrafter.com/publish/product/SquareDeck).

Comment: For this game, there are a great many possible squares, with only a few in use at any time.  Tiles ended up adding too much volume to the product.

Comment: What about multiple cards? One for apples, one for Triremes and a third for money?

Comment: @Anzeo, the square grid of the game is very important.  Each square may have apples, triremes, and money on it.  To break up that square into three different cards would be hard to reconcile with the square grid nature.

Comment: @Joe - sounds like you may need to reengineer the game format :)

Comment: @warren, no need for that -- this game's about to go to print with large square cards.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Jungle Speed uses 80x80mm cards with rounded corners.